# UWP XAML binding a Observable Collection class property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, uwp

I have a problem - I want to bind into a GridView a class property which is a ObservableCollection.

the class code:

```
public class Moment
{
  ...
  public ObservableCollection<Uri> PhotoFilePath { get; set; }
}



XAML

<GridView Grid.Row="0"
              Name="PhotosGridView"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind moment}">
```

moment is a instance of Moment in MainPage.xaml

```
       <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Moment">

                <Image Width="75"  Height="75">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="{x:Bind PhotoFilePath}" />
```

here i get
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Invalid binding path 'PhotoFilePath' : Cannot bind type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(System.Uri)' to 'System.Uri' without a converter

```
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>



            </DataTemplate>
       </GridView.ItemTemplate>

    </GridView>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The way you have it right now doesn't seem to make sense. `moment` is an instance of `Moment`, not a list of things (which is what `ItemsSource` expects). The list of things is the `PhotoFilePath` property on `Moment` (which, as an aside, is poorly named since it is a collection, not a single path).

I'm assuming what you really want to do is bind `ItemsSource` to `moment.PhotoFilePath`:

```
ItemsSource="{x:Bind moment.PhotoFilePath}">
```

You'll need to change your DataTemplate to just target a Uri:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="Uri">
```

Note that I am not positive if you can just say "Uri" there. I don't have a UWP project in front of me.

and then UriSource to each item inside of that property:

```
<BitmapImage UriSource="{x:Bind}" />
```

Comment: thx for reply. unfortunatelly there's still something wrong. Visual Studio says in that line  <BitmapImage UriSource="{x:Bind}" /> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I realized I left out one part of my answer. Does that help? I'm doing it without a UWP project in front of me, but it should be close.

Answer (score 0):

The UriSource property of BitmapImage expects type 'System.Uri'
but you are trying to bind it to 'ObservableCollection of System.Uri'

(PhotoFilePath property of your Moment class is an ObservableCollection of System.Uri)

The answer is in the error message 
*'Cannot bind type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(System.Uri)' to 'System.Uri'*